# Remove empty objects, arrays, strings or integers from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following snippet that is not working and decided to isolate it into a nodejs script:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let derpObject = {
    foo: "hey",
    bar: "",
    foo2: [],
    bar2: {}
}

function cleanObject(params) {
    const newObject = Object.keys(params).forEach( key => {
    console.log(params[key]);
        if(_.isNil(params[key]) || _.isEmpty(params[key])) {
      delete params[key]
    }
    });
  console.log('here', newObject);
  return newObject;
}

let result = cleanObject(derpObject);
console.log(result);
```

Basically my purpose is to check what properties are either empty or null from the main object and remove them and at the end return the new object with just the non empty/null properties.

However, running the above script outputs:

```
hey

[]
{}
here undefined
undefined
=> undefined
```

Any idea why I'm getting undefined? I've been banging my head with this one for a while now

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything

Comment: You're mutating the original object, so just do `return params`

Comment: Why not taking advantage of Lodash functions: `_.filter(derpObject, (e) => !_.isEmpty(e))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.forEach()` does not return anything hence `undefined` output, you might try assigning the values to new object and avoid changing the original object:

```js
function cleanObject(params) {
  const newObject = {};
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
    //console.log(params[key]);
    if (!(_.isNil(params[key]) || _.isEmpty(params[key]))) {
        newObject[key] = params[key]
    }
  });
  //console.log('here', newObject);
  return newObject;
}
```

```js
let derpObject = {
  foo: "hey",
  bar: "",
  foo2: [],
  bar2: {}
}

function cleanObject(params) {
  const newObject = {};
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
    //console.log(params[key]);
    if (!(_.isNil(params[key]) || _.isEmpty(params[key]))) {
        newObject[key] = params[key]
    }
  });
  //console.log('here', newObject);
  return newObject;
}

let result = cleanObject(derpObject);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Pure lodash:

```js
function cleanObject(params) {
  return _(params).omitBy(_.isNil).omitBy(_.isEmpty);
}
```

```js
let derpObject = {
  foo: "hey",
  bar: "",
  foo2: [],
  bar2: {}
}

function cleanObject(params) {
  return _(params).omitBy(_.isNil).omitBy(_.isEmpty);
}

console.log(cleanObject(derpObject));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. I changed the logic a bit so that it will add the object key and value if the value is valid (not is nil or not is empty)

```
function cleanObject(params) {
    let newObject = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach( key => {
        console.log(params[key]);
        if(!_.isNil(params[key]) || !_.isEmpty(params[key])) {
            newObject[key] = params[key]
        }
    });
  console.log('here', newObject);
  return newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Lodash#isNil()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil) and [Lodash#isEmpty()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty)

Code:

```js
const derpObject = {
  foo: "hey",
  bar: "",
  foo2: [],
  bar2: {}
}
const cleanObject = (o) => Object
  .keys(o)
  .reduce((a, k) => {
    if (!(_.isNil(o[k]) || _.isEmpty(o[k]))) {
      a[k] = o[k]
    }
    return a
  },{})
const result = cleanObject(derpObject)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```